# Combine if statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have tried answers on previously asked questions in relation to this, but cannot seem to get it to work.

I have an Excel sheet as shown here:

[image]

Beside provider, I have a drop down menu - Test1, Test2 and a blank,
Under year, I have a drop down menu - 2019, 2018

I can only do this with one provider.

Query: When Test1 is select with year 2018 or 2019, I wish for the amount provided and cancelled to show for Test1 (this I have done).

```
IF(Provider=Test1,IF(YEAR=2019,A1,IF(YEAR=2018,A2,"")))
```

But I want to be able to select either Test1 or Test2 and either 2018 or 2019
and the figures to show for what I have selected

`A1 = 2019` figure for Test1
`A2 = 2018` figure for Test1

Answer (score 0):

[my replicated example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BqIM.png)

- Cell A1 **50**   = test1 2019 figure
- Cell A2 **60**   = test1 2018 figure
- Cell A3 **75**   = test2 2019 figure
- Cell A4 **99**   = test2 2018 figure

Cell B6 Formula = `=IF(E1="test1",IF(E3=2019,A1,A2),IF(E3=2019,A3,A4))`

This is basically:

```
if E1 = "test1" then
  if E3 = 2019 then 
    print value of cell A1
  else
    print value of cell A2
  end if
else
  if E3 = 2019 then 
    print value of cell A3
  else
    print value of cell A4
  end if
end if
```

Of course the values that are looked up will be changed for your requirements. And you'll do the same for your Cancelled value lookup. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you but the only figures that show are for TEST 1, im looking to add if TEST 2 in Cell then the A3, A4 will be shown

Comment: Yes, that's the 'else' part in the statement, `... ,IF(E3=2019,A3,A4))` meaning if it's not test1, then do the same check for 2019 again, and print A3, if it's not 2019, then print A4... Or am I misunderstanding your requirement completely?